# Android 10 cannot register Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am currently developing a Application to track Steps.

In order to track steps i am using the following Sensor of the phone: **Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER**

This worked fine for all devices I tested it with. Recently I had the chance to test the application on Samsung S10 device, but it did not track the steps anymore whereas it worked on Android 9 of the Samsung S9. It also works fine on a Google Nexus running Android 6.

## **The question that now arises is whether this has to do with my code or if it is an Issue with Android 10?**

**I found the following warning when running the application:**

- *2020-01-06 17:13:30.381 24261-24261/? D/SensorManager: registerListener fail (1) :: 17, SAMSUNG Step Counter Sensor, 200000,
  0,*

**Some Additional Debug info:**

- *Sensor name="SAMSUNG Step Detector Sensor", vendor="Samsung Inc.", version=1, type=18, maxRange=1.0, resolution=1.0, power=0.3, minDelay=0*

*Debug Infos are somewhat mixed as I tested both the Step Counter Sensor and the Step Detector Sensor both yield the same result.*

**My Code to register the Sensor:**

```
 private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    /**
     * This Method gets called on each Sensor Trigger event
     *
     * @param sensorEvent Event created by Sensor
     */
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        //ME COUNTING STEPS
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
        //Nothing to do here
    }
};

private SensorManager sensorManager;

/**
 * Function that initialises all the Sensors
 * Sets SensorManager
 * Sets Sensor to monitor to STEP Counter
 * Also Registers the Sensor
 */
private void initSensors() {
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    assert sensorManager != null;
    Sensor stepSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);

    if (stepSensor == null) {
        createToastMessage("Sensor not found.");
        selectedFragment = new NoSensor_Fragment();
        activeFragment = 5;
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                selectedFragment).commit();
    } else {
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, stepSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        hasSensor = true;
    }
}
```

**I found a solution for this issue**

In my case it was simple mistake with Permissions. On Android 10 you need to ask for Permissions to gain Access to the Step Sensors. Which is something I overlooked when reading the changes for Android 10. I Added the following to the **Manifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
```

And added the following in the **onCreate** Method:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
        //ask for permission
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION}, PHYISCAL_ACTIVITY);
    }
```

Hope this helps people facing the same issue as me.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so people can benefit more from your question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Possible Solution**

In my case it was simple mistake with Permissions. On Android 10 you need to ask for Permissions to gain Access to the Step Sensors. Which is something I overlooked when reading the changes for Android 10. I Added the following to the **Manifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
```

And added the following in the **onCreate** Method:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
        //ask for permission
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION}, PHYISCAL_ACTIVITY);
    }
```

Hope this helps people facing the same issue as me.

Comment: PHYISCAL_ACTIVITY, was the request code I used for that specific Permission, you can specify the request code yourself. You can refer to the Android Permission documentation for further details.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting