# step counting sensor not working on real devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, sensors

i have code for step counting sensor
but i run this code on my devices and it is not working

```
override fun init_events() {
```

```
        sensoreManager=getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        if(sensoreManager!!.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)!=null)
        {

            sensor=sensoreManager!!.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)
            running=true
            showToastMessage("yes")
        }else{
           showToastMessage("no")
            running=false
        }
```

```
}
```

```
    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {
        Log.i("TEST_TEST","ssssssssssss")
       
    }
```

```
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
        Log.i("TEST_TEST","ssssssssssss")
        if(event!!.sensor==sensor)
            showToastMessage("movment")

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        Log.i("TEST_TEST","f RESume")

        super.onResume()
        if(sensoreManager!!.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)!=null){
            sensoreManager!!.registerListener(this,sensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
            Log.i("TEST_TEST","not null")}
        else{
            Log.i("TEST_TEST","null")
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        Log.i("TEST_TEST","f onPause")
        super.onPause()
        if(sensoreManager!!.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)!=null)
           sensoreManager!!.unregisterListener(this,sensor)
    }
```

what wrong on this code
my device xiaomi note 9 pro

Comment: Does the accelerometer of the device work in any other apps on the phone?

Comment: Yes i download many apps on google play and it work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592685/android-10-cannot-register-sensor-type-step-counter

Answer (score 0):

the anser in this code
you have to accept permission in android 10

````
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
        //ask for permission
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION}, PHYISCAL_ACTIVITY);
    }
    ```
````