# Android STEP_COUNTER sensor is null (Samsung Z Flip)

Tags: android, kotlin, pedometer

I am currently developing a Application to track Steps.

In order to track steps i am using the following Sensor of the phone: Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER

This worked fine for all devices I tested it with.
But, it started to fail after updating "ONE UI" and "ANDROID 13" for the phone(SM-F711N)
that worked well.

Phone has FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER but default sensor is null
What is Problem?
Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Here's my logging code and result

```
Log.e("test","hasSystemFeature - SENSOR-STEP-COUNTER" + packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER));

Log.e("test","step sensor list: ${mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)}")
Log.e("test", "step counter default sensor: ${mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)}" )
```

[image]

Comment: looks like some bug in system release... personally I doubt you can do anything with that, besides reporting to manufacturer

Comment: You think so, too?
I'll have to contact Samsung.
I think this update has caused more people to have this problem.

Comment: [This may help gentleman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592685/android-10-cannot-register-sensor-type-step-counter)

Comment: My issue's not  about permissions